# $\forall A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}, \exists S^T=S\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}(invertible)$, s.t. $AS=SA^T$ (Hua's Lemma(1944))

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Prove: $\forall A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $\sigma(A)\subset \mathbb R$, $\exists S^T=S\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}(invertible)$ such that $AS$ is symmetric. (The title is incomplete due to character limit sorry for that)

Our teacher posted this problem in an exam. We were first asked to prove it when $n=2$, then asked to prove it when $A$ is a Jordan block. I solved these two problems, but failed to prove it for all $A$'s.

I attempted to search for it but failed. I guess the real *Hua's Lemma* is probably more generalized?

Comment: How about $S=0$?

Comment: sorry i forgot to note that $S$ is invertible

Comment: This is an exam question and you ask us to help you to cheat on it?!

Comment: No i dont mean this lol. This problem was given by our professors to other students a few years ago, and I saw it yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J=P^{-1}AP$ be the Jordan form of $A$, where $P$ can be chosen to be real because $A$ has a real spectrum. If you can find a real symmetric invertible matrix $X$ such that $X^{-1}JX=J^T$, then
$$
P^{-T}X^{-1}P^{-1}APXP^T=A^T,
$$
where $P^{-T}$ denotes $(P^{-1})^T=(P^T)^{-1}$. That is, $S^{-1}AS=A^T$ where $S=PXP^T$ is symmetric. Hence $AS=SA^T=(AS)^T$.